# stream audio from RTMP url inside a web page with javascript and html5

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio, rtmp

i am using a react javascript app and i have an audio streaming that is streamed from  RTMP url,
is there any solution to read it or to stream it.
what i tried is jwplayer

```
<div id="myElement"></div><script>
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
  file: "rtmp://draco.streamingwizard.com/wizard/_definst_/demo/mp3/KanyeWestBeachBoys.mp3",
  width: 480,
  height: 30
});</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, a web browser can not read an RTMP stream without flash.

Comment: is there any way to use javascript with a bibliothèque that can run audio player to listen to a streaming over RTMP

Comment: No, a web browser can not read an RTMP stream without flash. Period.